# I need a data structure to hold two data types

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am making a binary tree and when I add a new string node to the tree, I must first search to see if that node already exists.  If it does, I need to increase its value by one instead of adding it to a different node.

Which data structure would be best to do this with?

Comment: Just us a Node class with the string and a counter.

Comment: Any DataStructure will work , it only matters how you are reading the string and appending a Integer in the end. So even a String with a integer prefix will work

Comment: True, but it's not clear to me that that's "best".

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood you, your question is very easy. Just create a class that holds two member variables:

```
public class Node {
    v1 data_type_1;
    v2 data_type_2;
}
```

Use this as nodes for your binary tree.

Comment: This answer is good, but would be stronger if Node contained well-named String and int members

Answer (score 1):

Barney's answer is good. But to answer your question a little more specifically, you will probably want your node class to look like:

```
public class Node
{
    String value;
    int count;

    Node leftChild;
    Node rightChild;
}
```

You'll be creating instances of these for your tree. One of these instances will be the "root". All other instances will hang directly or indirectly off the route, via `leftChild` and `rightChild`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Huh, essentially maybe

https://github.com/JohannesLichtenberger/sirix/tree/master/bundles/sirix-core/src/main/java/org/sirix/index/avltree

helps. It's an implementation of an AVLTree, a binary tree which is balanced. I'd implement it with generic types (and I have), such that you are able to store other content as well.

In my case it's used as an index-structure which should be able to be stored in main-memory for the most part (but also with an on-disk representation which uses versioning algorithms). I'm storing a String/Path combination (key) and a simple set of IDs belonging to the path (value).

However, you probably have to store either two "pointers" to the two child-nodes or in-memory references to two Node-objects.

Edit: You might also take a sharp look at the upcoming BinaryTreeTraverser from Google Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/BinaryTreeTraverser.java

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above. If you can't provide that, consider [writing a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) instead.

Answer (score 0):

So the motto of the Structure is to minimize memory by reducing duplicates with their count . And storing data in a sorted order .

This node could be of some use for your tree then .

```
public class node
{
   String value;
   int count;
   node left;
   node right;
}
```

But there is better solution then this even It is TreeMap , because search here takes O(1) (duplicate count increment is equivalent to search )where as O(log(n)) in the previous case .

```
Map testTreeMap = new TreeMap();
if(testTreeMap.get(MyString)!=null)
{
testTreeMap.put(MyString, testTreeMap.get(MyString) +1)
}
else
{
testTreeMap.put( MyString , Integer(count) ) // count=1
}
```

With this you are totally done..!!

http://tutorialswithexamples.com/java-treemap-tutorial-and-examples/